# Matching names on form Firstname Lastname with international characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to catch firstnames by making the assumtion that they are on the form `Firstname Lastlame`. This works good with the code below, but I would like to be able to catch international names like `Pär Åberg`. I found some solutions but they does unfortunally not seem to work with Python flavoured regexp. Anyone with insighs to this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import re

text = """
This is a text containing names of people in the text such as 
Hillary Clinton or Barack Obama. My problem is with names that uses stuff 
outside A-Z like Swedish names such as Pär Åberg."""

for name in re.findall("(([A-Z])[\w-]*(\s+[A-Z][\w-]*)+)", text):
    firstname = name[0].split()[0]
    print firstname
```

Comment: carefull with capturing groups and findall.

Comment: For lastname you could search for any character between spaces

Comment: try `re.findall(r'[A-Z][\w-]*(?:\s+[A-Z][\w-]*)+')`

Comment: The correct answer is use `regex` module with `r'\p{Lu}[\w-]*(?:\s+\p{Lu}[\w-]*)+'`.

Comment: Expanding on what @stribizhev said, you need to include the Local (`L`) and Unicode (`u`) flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an alternative [regex library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) as there you can use `\p{L}` - *any Unicode letter*.

Then, use

```
ur'\p{Lu}[\w-]*(?:\s+\p{Lu}[\w-]*)+'
```

When using a Unicode string to initialize regex, the `UNICODE` flag is used automatically:

> If neither the `ASCII`, `LOCALE` nor `UNICODE` flag is specified, it will default to `UNICODE` if the regex pattern is a Unicode string and `ASCII` if it’s a bytestring.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Beyond updating with your regex I just needed to edit ´firstname = name[0].split()[0]´ to ´firstname = name.split()[0]´.